# Can you auto subscribe to a podcast directly from an iphone?

Tags: itunes, podcasts

Normally I subscribe to podcasts from my Mac and it downloads the latest ones automatically.  I was told that I can now just download podcasts from my iphone directly.  I didn't see any ability to subscribe to podcasts directly from the iphone.  Is that possible so when i wake up in the morning i automatically have the latest episodes downloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like with the updated podcast app (1.1) you can autodownload podcasts when you are in WIKI area

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you can subscribe to podcasts within Apple's own [Podcasts](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/podcasts/id525463029?mt=8) app. You can, however, subscribe to any podcast with the excellent [Downcast](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/downcast/id393858566?mt=8) app.

With Downcast you can set it to check for podcasts at a certain area. For example, when you get home, it will check for and download your podcasts.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Podcasts icon]

Apple's free [Podcasts](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/podcasts/id525463029?mt=8) app can indeed subscribe to podcasts (and it interfaces with the Music app's database, so the podcasts show up there as well). However because iOS apps are restricted from running schedule tasks in the background, *you can't have it update every morning*.

[Downcast](http://www.downcastapp.com/) and [Instacast](http://vemedio.com/products/instacast) are the two most popular 3rd party apps, both will subscribe and download podcasts, but have the same restrictions—no scheduled background checks for new episodes, but Downcast does support location-based triggers to check for and download new episodes.